# Is there any api to connect internet using Ethernet in android

Tags: android

I have implemented code for connect internet through WifiManager.java. but i am not able to find any api to connect internet through Ethernet. Can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of.

Here is a method that detected WIFI and Data separately.
Perhaps you can alter this and put a prompt in there forcing user to turn off data and turn on WIFI.

```
public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {
    boolean isConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean isConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                isConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                isConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return isConnectedWifi || isConnectedMobile;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ali. Actually I wanted to implement code to connect internet through Ethernet using ipaddress, subnet mask, default gateway and DNS properties.